# building real simulation in multisim(NI company) of dc-dc SEPIC convertor

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, sepic

hi I am trying to build  real simulationin multisim of dc-dc SEPIC convertor how ever in my output voltage i get a lot of RIPPLE . the problem is that I get a lot of spikes in my capacitor current . how to fix this problem ?

this the schem 
[image]

and this is the current of capsitor C1  : 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try adding some parasitics to the sensitive nodes near the capacitor; I suspect that will reduce those spikes.

Comment: Please don't use a screenshot to give us the schematic. Export a proper graphic from Multisim and include that instead.

Comment: you mean adding capacitor in series ?